# What does type Props mean in react and typescript when used with Omit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dates

I am new to using typescript and react-dates package.
I am not sure what the below type means

```
type Props = Omit<
    DayPickerRangeControllerShape,
    | 'numberOfMonths'
    | 'focusedInput'
    | 'onFocusChange'
    | 'hideKeyboardShortcutsPanel'
    | 'noBorder'
>;

function DateRangePicker(props: Props) {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <DayPickerRangeController
                {...props}
                numberOfMonths={3}
                onFocusChange={noop}
                hideKeyboardShortcutsPanel
                noBorder
                horizontalMonthPadding={32}
                dayPickerNavigationInlineStyles={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                }}
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
```

What does the type `Props` with `Omit` do here in this case?

Comment: Please note that `Omit` is a big part of your question and should be in the title (I've made some small updates to try and help out). The code is also case-sensitive, so `Omit` and `omit` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `function DateRangePicker(props: Props)` means that `DateRangePicker` component props should be compatible with `Props` type that is defined earlier.

And this block

```
type Props = Omit<
    DayPickerRangeControllerShape,
    | 'numberOfMonths'
    | 'focusedInput'
    | 'onFocusChange'
    | 'hideKeyboardShortcutsPanel'
    | 'noBorder'
>;
```

means that type `Props` should be equal to `DayPickerRangeControllerShape` interface, but without some of the fields, like `numberOfMonths`, `focusedInput` and etc.

`Omit` basically strips (removes) some fields from interface or type which you pass to it.

Answer (score 2):

Stating Typescript,

> `Omit<Type, Keys>` Constructs a type by picking all properties from
> Type and then removing Keys.

Basically, you can use `Omit` to create a new type from an already existing type by removing certain properties.

For example,

```
interface Employee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type EmployeeWithoutName = Omit<Employee, "name">;

const employee: Employee = {
  id: 1
  name: "Richard"
};

const employeeWithoutName: EmployeeWithoutName = {
  id: 1
};

employeeWithoutName.name = "Jones"; // Throws an error.
```

Answer (score 0):

In react props represent the property, which is generally passed form one component to another component.